# Problem Subtracting Values fom a column for two Dataframes with the same dates in for loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have two dataframes which look like the following:

df1:

```
DATE        Value1  Value2
04.01.05    2.754   2.757
05.01.05    2.7316  2.7505
06.01.05    2.7546  2.7568
07.01.05    2.7465  2.7525
10.01.05    2.7385  2.7415
11.01.05    2.7348  2.7388
12.01.05    2.7348  2.7388
13.01.05    2.7348  2.7388
14.01.05    2.7365  2.7435
17.01.05    2.7365  2.7435
18.01.05    2.7365  2.7435
19.01.05    2.7365  2.7435
```

df2:

```
DATE        Value1  Value2
04.01.05    2.701   2.6995
05.01.05    2.7065  2.705
07.01.05    2.6348  2.6333
10.01.05    2.635   2.6315
11.01.05    2.6275  2.6265
12.01.05    2.6268  2.6253
13.01.05    2.6285  2.627
17.01.05    2.6565  2.6555
18.01.05    2.6275  2.626
19.01.05    2.643   2.6415
```

If I jhave the exact same dates my code below works. As soon as dates are not euqal and I only want to calculate for dates which are equal it is not working. My if statement somehow does not filter the proper dates out. I would like to add the calculated value to df1.

My code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = 'File1.csv'
file2 = 'File2.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep=';')
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE)

df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, sep=';')
df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.DATE)

for date1 in df1['DATE']:
    for date2 in df2['DATE']:
        if date1 == date2:
            print(date1, date2)
            df1['sub'] = df1.Value1 - df2.Value1

print(df1)
```

The expected output would be the following:

```
DATE        Value1  Value2  LEVEL   sub
04.01.05    2.701   2.6995  1 Year  0.053
05.01.05    2.7065  2.705   1 Year  0.0251
07.01.05    2.6348  2.6333  1 Year  0.1117
10.01.05    2.635   2.6315  1 Year  0.1035
11.01.05    2.6275  2.6265  1 Year  0.1073
12.01.05    2.6268  2.6253  1 Year  0.108
13.01.05    2.6285  2.627   1 Year  0.1063
17.01.05    2.6565  2.6555  1 Year  0.08
18.01.05    2.6275  2.626   1 Year  0.109
19.01.05    2.643   2.6415  1 Year  0.0935
```

This means only the difference will be calculated for equal dates.

Comment: no need to use loop, check panadas merge and take the diff then

Comment: and how will that go with non equal dates? And why should I merge the dataframes? I would just add the one calc into it

Comment: @ALollz, Thanks for the answer. I included the expected output. This sounds like the way I want. Can you include that as a solution?

Comment: @ALollz, so you mean that '
dt = df1.copy()
dt['sub'] = df1['Value1'].sub(df2['Value1'], axis=0)' This will also not work

Comment: check and try my answer, it will drop all non equal dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the index to `'DATE'` so that it will align. Then we subtract. Since you seem to want the output added to `df2` we will do `-(df2 - df1)` which is the same as `(df1 - df2)`

```
df1 = df1.set_index('DATE')
df2 = df2.set_index('DATE')

df2['sub'] = -df2['Value1'].sub(df1['Value1'])

          Value1  Value2     sub
DATE                            
04.01.05  2.7010  2.6995  0.0530
05.01.05  2.7065  2.7050  0.0251
07.01.05  2.6348  2.6333  0.1117
10.01.05  2.6350  2.6315  0.1035
11.01.05  2.6275  2.6265  0.1073
12.01.05  2.6268  2.6253  0.1080
13.01.05  2.6285  2.6270  0.1063
17.01.05  2.6565  2.6555  0.0800
18.01.05  2.6275  2.6260  0.1090
19.01.05  2.6430  2.6415  0.0935
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. I somehow receive the error message: raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @NewNY1990 seems you have dates repeated in one or both of the DataFrames. How do you handle subtraction in that case, as it's unclear what should align?

Comment: No dates are unique for every file bute the same between both files except that one file has less dates and I only want the subtraction for the same dates

Comment: @NewNY1990 I really don't think that's the case. That error is telling you that there are duplicates. Look at `df1['DATE'].duplicated().sum()` and `df2['DATE'].duplicated().sum()`. I'm pretty sure you should get a non-zero answer for at least one of those.

Comment: I fixed it. There was an issue with the csv file at the end. There were some emty lines in it with N/A shown. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```py
# this will result in merged df wtih all intersecting dates
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on = 'DATE', suffixes=('','_df2')
# the column you need
df1['sub'] = df1['Value1'] - df1['Value1_df2'] 
# next drop unnecessary columns of df2
df1.drop(columns = ['Value1_df2', 'Value2_df2'], inplace=True)
```